Why naturality in Yoneda Lemma?
I understand the statement of Yoneda Lemma and its implications; however, at a very concrete level I have never seen how naturality condition is used in examples. Even when we consider a Yoneda embedding, the naturality condition is not used to show fullness of the functor. I wonder if someone could explain why the naturality is so crucial, or perhaps provide a motivation of 'how things would be different' if it was not to hold.
To clarify, I refer to naturality in the following sense (this is taken from Tom Leinster's Basic Category Theory p95):

This question might not sound concrete enough, compared to some popular 'confusions with Yoneda', but I think it might help for other beginners as myself. This naturality condition is somewhat implicit, and yet there are many similar instances in which naturality condition can't be ignored. For instance, when you learn about adjuctions you get to see that naturality in both arguments is constantly used to prove important results such as correspondence between co(units) and adjunctions or General Adjoint Functor Theorem. I wonder what is the importance of naturality in the case of Yoneda Lemma.

Can you specify what you call "the naturality condition"?

@CaptainLama sure! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma has a section on naturality between two functors $C\times Set^C\rightarrow Set$

To be specific, are you asking what happens in the Yoneda lemma if instead of "natural transformations" you write "transformations, not necessarily natural"? Have you worked out an example of what happens here for the case of, say, a one-object category?

@Tanizaki Linking to Wikipedia is a good start but please edit your question to be more self-contained and explain what naturality condition you have in mind, given that there seems to be some confusion :)

Are you really sure you don't use naturality of Yoneda? Because it is implicitly used all the time. Every time you see "$\cong$" in category theory, you should have in the back of your mind: "the author probably means this is natural, but I need to ask myself why this is natural". It's left so implicit it gets fairly well forgotten, and stuff is assumed to work out

So if it isn't used in your specific case, trust me it'll get used eventually. It's also just nice to know. In category theory you very rarely want unnatural isomorphisms (partly because we implicitly and sloppily assume everything is always fine... so for that to have any hope of working, you need naturality as a starting point)

@FShrike Are you saying that the use of "$\cong$" is a kind of hand-waving which some authors believe to be justified by the magic word naturality?

If $F$ and $G$ are functors, then $F \cong G$ means $F$ and $G$ are naturally isomorphic. If you mean something different you should specify.

@Jochen not really. I’m just trying to alert the OP to the reality that people tend not to check naturality or its consequences in detail yet it is very important and frequently used!

@BenSteffan I have edited the question, hope it's clearer now!)))

Ah, so you are talking about the naturality of the Yoneda lemma itself (seen as a natural isomorphism between two evaluation functors), rather than the naturality in the hypotheses of the Yoneda lemma? Since this is just a theorem, it's not clear that you can meaningfully ask how things would be if it didn't hold, like asking how the universe would look like if $\pi$ was $4$.
